# Updating a whole array in VueJs in an efficient way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, reference-type

I need to update a really long array based on the input value of a selection field.
Since the mutation problems of reference types, the way to detect changed are methods like `splice`. Using `splice()` did not empty the array however, I don´t know why. I came across `Vue.set(data, index, value)` which works and my current solution is this:

```
  if (this.selectval === "fizz") {
    const newarr = [35, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];
    for (let i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) {
      Vue.set(this.$store.state.country, i, newarr[i]);
    }
  }
```

However, in this already very small example, the code seems to be too complicated just to change the data in an entire array. Are there any options which are more concise and come close to my desired `this.$store.state.country = newdata` ?

Answer (score 2):

you can just set it normally like you want to:

```
this.$store.state.country = newarr;
```

Vue.set is only necessary for updating elements within an array because of the way javascript handles array element references.  You can always just replace the whole thing.